# How do I use Vue3 + TypeScript v-model on textfield? "ERROR: Invalid assignment target"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, v-model

## *Full Error:*

```js
[plugin:vite:vue] Transform failed with 1 error:
/home/projects/vue3-vite-typescript-starter-jkcbyx/src/App.vue:33:73: 
ERROR: Invalid assignment target

"/home/projects/vue3-vite-typescript-starter-jkcbyx/src/App.vue:33:73"

Invalid assignment target
31 |        ? (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("div", _hoisted_2, [
32 |            _withDirectives(_createElementVNode("textarea", {
33 |              "onUpdate:modelValue": _cache[0] || (_cache[0] = $event => (($setup.np?.description) = $event))
   |                                                                           ^
34 |            }, null, 512 /* NEED_PATCH */), [
35 |              [
```

### Here is the `App.vue`:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

interface Thing {
  description: string
}

const np = ref<Thing>({
  description: 'asdf asdf asdf',
})
</script>

<template>
  {{ np?.description }}
  <br />
  <textarea v-model.trim="np?.description"></textarea>
</template>
```

### HERE is a Full recreation of the error:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-typescript-starter-jkcbyx?file=src/App.vue

---

Any help here is appreciated <3
This problem is rather confounding.

Comment: may be worth noting the same error is given if `const np = reactive<>()` is used instead.

Comment: Your code is fine, but the template doesn't seem to be able to handle the optional chaining operator at `v-model="np?.description"`.  This may be due to the versions of Vite/compilers that stackblitz is using. If you remove the operator it compiles fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use dual-binding (`v-model`) with optional chaining (`np?.description`). Dual binding means getter & setter. What do you expect the setter to set when `np` is falsey? I know you wrapped it in `v-if` but optional chaining tells `v-model` the target object structure is possibly `undefined`, and that's an invalid assignment target.

One way to go about it is create a `description` computed, where you specify how to set `np.description` when the current value of `np` allows it:

```js
const description = computed({
  get() {
    return np.value?.description || ''
  },
  set(description) {
    if (typeof np.value?.description === 'string') {
      np.value = { ...np.value, description }
    }
  },
})
```

See it working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-typescript-starter-wrvbqw?file=src%2FApp.vue

---

The above is a pretty generic solution (when you actually ***do** need* to use optional chaining with `v-model`).
A simpler alternative, in your case (possible because you wrapped the `<textarea>` in `v-if="np"`), is not using optional chaining with `v-model` at all:
replace `v-model.trim="np?.description"` with `v-model.trim="np.description"`.

It will work.

Comment: Yep, that was it, Thank you so much. I didn't question the `?` because when I hit "tab" in my editor to auto-complete, it put a `?` in there. I feel dumb

Comment: Don't! JavaScript is tricky, by nature. I learn things about it every day, and I've been at it for quite some time now. Happy coding!